# BIRT report generation in 4.5.0 throws invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, birt

We had upgraded BIRT to 4.5.0 recently from 2.6 and all the report design developed with the older version are working fine with 4.5.0 except one.

The report generation is successful but the HTML report is showing the following error 
`"org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)"`

I am very new to BIRT and I couldn't understand what is causing this issue. It would be great if someone help me understand the root cause of this issue.

Stack Trace shown in HTML report file:

```
The following items have errors:

OdaDataSet AllFloors:
- invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

birt.core.JavascriptError ( 1 time(s) )
detail : org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.prepare(AbstractDataEngine.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ReportExecutor.execute(ReportExecutor.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedReportExecutor.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplciateReportExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplciateReportExecutor.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedReportExecutor.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportExecutor.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at com.trapeze.appl.shared.reports.AbstractReportGenerator.generateHTMLReport(AbstractReportGenerator.java:942)
    at com.trapeze.appl.shared.reports.AbstractReportGenerator.generateReport(AbstractReportGenerator.java:838)
    at com.trapeze.appl.shared.reports.ReportService$1.generate(ReportService.java:98)
    at com.trapeze.appl.rm.server.reports.RMReportService.generateReport(RMReportService.java:289)
    at com.trapeze.appl.rm.server.reports.RMReportService.generateClientReport(RMReportService.java:426)
    at com.trapeze.appl.shared.reports.ReportServlet.generateClientSideReportByXML(ReportServlet.java:215)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianSkeleton.invoke(HessianSkeleton.java:180)
    at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianSkeleton.invoke(HessianSkeleton.java:109)
    at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianServlet.service(HessianServlet.java:396)
    at com.trapeze.fw.services.server.HessianServiceServlet.service(HessianServiceServlet.java:93)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:677)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:568)
    at org.mortbay.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
    at org.mortbay.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
    at org.mortbay.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
    at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.mortbay.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:245)
    at org.mortbay.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.mortbay.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.CoreException: invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.wrapRhinoException(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateRawScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.internal.adapter.OdaDataSourceAdapter.<init>(OdaDataSourceAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.ModelAdapter.adaptDataSource(ModelAdapter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.adapter.ModelDteApiAdapter.createDataSourceDesign(ModelDteApiAdapter.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.adapter.ModelDteApiAdapter.doDefineDataSource(ModelDteApiAdapter.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.adapter.ModelDteApiAdapter.defineDataSet(ModelDteApiAdapter.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.prepare(AbstractDataEngine.java:159)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:77)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.error(DefaultErrorReporter.java:64)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:188)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:166)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:223)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:210)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:203)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.TokenStream.readRegExp(TokenStream.java:921)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.primaryExpr(Parser.java:2798)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.memberExpr(Parser.java:2406)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Parser.java:2304)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Parser.java:2229)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Parser.java:2213)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Parser.java:2194)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Parser.java:2169)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Parser.java:2141)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Parser.java:2130)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Parser.java:2119)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Parser.java:2108)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Parser.java:2097)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Parser.java:2086)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Parser.java:2062)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Parser.java:2033)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.expr(Parser.java:2012)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1039)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.nameOrLabel(Parser.java:1793)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1032)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:901)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statements(Parser.java:856)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.block(Parser.java:1688)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1010)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:901)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.ifStatement(Parser.java:1082)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:947)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:901)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:540)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:478)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2348)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1335)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1324)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.getCompiledScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateRawScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:95)
    ... 40 more




OdaDataSet AllDevices:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet AllAPs:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet APClosetDistance:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet APClosetDistanceInOneAP:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet APSingnalStrength:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet GraphRssiHeatMap:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet HeatMapLegend:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet AllFloorContourGraph:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet AllAPContourGraph:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet AllRFPoint:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet AllRFPointSS_A:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet AllRFPointSS_B:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet APInventory:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

OdaDataSet DeviceInventory:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

TabularCube MPCube:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

TabularCube MXCube:
+ invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)

List (id = 27425):
+ DataSet "APDistance" is not defined in report. 

ReportDesign (id = 1):
+ An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
invalid flag after regular expression (<inline>#2)
```

Snippet of the report design file (OdaDataSet)

```
    <data-sets>
        <oda-data-set extensionID="org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.dataSet" name="AllFloors" id="1707">
            <structure name="cachedMetaData">
                <list-property name="resultSet">
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">1</property>
                        <property name="name">id</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                        ....
                        ....
                        ....
            <property name="dataSource">reportDataSource</property>
            <list-property name="resultSet">
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">1</property>
                    <property name="name">id</property>
                    <property name="nativeName">id</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    <property name="nativeDataType">12</property>
                </structure>
                ....
                ....
            <xml-property name="queryText"><![CDATA[table0#-TNAME-#table0#:#[//FLOOR]#:#{id;STRING;@id}, .... ]]></xml-property>
            <xml-property name="designerValues"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model:DesignValues xmlns:design="http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/connectivity/oda/design" xmlns:model="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/report/model/adapter/odaModel">
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <design:ResultSets derivedMetaData="true">
    <design:resultSetDefinitions>
      <design:resultSetColumns>
        <design:resultColumnDefinitions>
          <design:attributes>
            <design:name>id</design:name>
            <design:position>1</design:position>
            <design:nativeDataTypeCode>12</design:nativeDataTypeCode>
            <design:precision>-1</design:precision>
            <design:scale>-1</design:scale>
            <design:nullability>Unknown</design:nullability>
          </design:attributes>
          <design:usageHints>
            <design:label>id</design:label>
            <design:formattingHints/>
          </design:usageHints>
        </design:resultColumnDefinitions>
        ....
      </design:resultSetColumns>
    </design:resultSetDefinitions>
  </design:ResultSets>
</model:DesignValues>]]></xml-property>
            <list-property name="privateDriverProperties">
                <ex-property>
                    <name>MAX_ROW</name>
                    <value>-1</value>
                </ex-property>
                <ex-property>
                    <name>XML_FILE</name>
                </ex-property>
            </list-property>
```

Java script snippet in the report design file:

```
<expression name="value">var servlet=reportContext.getHttpServletRequest();&#13;
    if(servlet != null &amp;&amp; servlet.getAttribute("attributeBean").isDesigner()   ){&#13;
        config[ "birt.viewer.working.path" ] + "/../../../path/to/sample/xml/data/file.xml";&#13;
    }</expression>
```

There were around 300 odd such occurrences in the design file. Is there a way in BIRT eclipse to identify what piece of java script code is causing this issue.

Comment: You could try opening the report template as XML file (instead of visual editor) and seeing if the JavaScript sections contain some regular expressions that are suspicious.

Comment: Thanks Teemu for your response. There were 300 odd expressions in the report design (updated the question with the piece of java script code). Is there a way in eclipse BIRT to identify the erroneous code ?

Comment: This may be unrelated to your problem, but I think the expression you give as an example is invalid anyway: What if the condition is not true? I think there should be an else clause.